# Cannot perform basic commands in Tcl package Snack

Tags: windows-7, package, tcl

I am trying to use a Tcl application called "[Linger](http://tedlab.mit.edu/~dr/Linger/)" (developed by Doug Rohde) in order to create a reading experiment. I need to use the package Snack in order to record subjects' repetitions of what they read. I got a number of error messages when trying the script in the application, all related to this package.

So, in Wish I tried to find out whether the package is correctly loaded.

```
package require snack
```

yields

```
couldn't load library "C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.6/snack2.2/libsnack.dll"
```

When first running

```
package provide snack 2.2.10
```

then

```
package require snack
```

it gives me

```
2.2.10
```

Does that mean the package is loaded?

I tried to solve this question by running one of the basic commands in [Snack's tutorial](http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/tutorial.html).

```
snack::sound s
```

should create a Snack sound object named `s`; when I try it, however, Wish gives me

```
invalid command name "snack::sound"
```

So now I know why my Linger script doesn't work, but I don't know how to solve the problem. I am very grateful for help or anyone pointing out a link with the answer.

I am running Tcl/Tk 8.6.3 and snack 2.2.10 on Windows 7 (64-bit). Tried the same on Mac OS 10.6 and Linux; same result.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the implementation of the package is not being loaded for some reason. Alas, the error diagnostic:

```
couldn't load library "C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.6/snack2.2/libsnack.dll"
```

isn't especially informative. If the file `C:\Tcl\lib\tcl8.6\snack2.2\libsnack.dll` exists (which you can check in Explorer; Tcl prefers to use Unix-style directory name separators internally) then it's most likely to be a 32-bit library vs 64-bit application (or *vice versa*) issue; you can't load mismatched libraries into running applications under anything remotely approaching normal circumstances.

Unfortunately, it seems that Snack is one of the packages that is most likely to be absent in a Tcl installation (it's not part of the ActiveTcl distribution, for example). You could try getting the code from the [Snack site](http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/download.html) but I think that likely will need a 32-bit build of Tcl/Tk to work, and we now default to 64-bit builds on most platforms. I don't know why Snack stopped being built as part of ActiveTcl.

---

Doing a

```
package provide snack 2.2.10
```

won't help you. It just tells a lie to the Tcl runtime about the package, but without the real implementation, you won't be able to use it. (Strictly, it's how a package implementation tells the package manager that it has successfully loaded. It should only be used by package implementations under normal circumstances.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick help! Running the application with the 32-bit version of Tcl did the trick. Be sure to find your name in my Acknowledgement chapter (if you don't mind)!

Answer (score 0):

If you will download and install [WinTclTk](http://wintcltk.sourceforge.net/) snack will work. WinTclTk has snack already included. So you don't have to install it manualy. Just type

*package require snack*

and you will get information about already included snack package.

I tried it on virtual Windows XP(32bit).

I was trying the snack software from [snack original site](http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/) on Windows 7(64bit) and Ubuntu(64bit) with no success.